# What is the difference betwee UniversalEncodingDetector and CharsetDetector for detecting encoding in apache tika?.

Tags: apache, character-encoding, apache-tika

Since both classes can be used for detecting the encoding of a file. Which one is more efficient and what are the basic difference between them? Please help.. apache version I am  using is 1.9

Comment: Why are you using an old version? 1.12 is the most recent

Comment: I have tried with the version 1.12 also. but the question remains same. Can you please help me with the differences mentioned above?